# Couldn't Seek Exception and Unable to load libtesseract3051.dll in Tess4j

Tags: ocr, tess4j

I need to do Character Recognition from Binary images.In order to perform that I'm using Tess4j library.While running the program I'm getting "**Couldn't Seek**" Exception and if I modify my  code,it shows Unable to load **libtesseract3051.dll**.Can anyone please help this?
Thanks in advance. Here I've attached the code.

```
public class Character {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File Image=new File("D:\\Education\\Project\\Reference\\Edge.tiff");
    ITesseract obj=new Tesseract();
    try
    {
        String op=obj.doOCR(Image);
        System.out.println(op);
    }
    catch(TesseractException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting error like this

```
 [main] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - Couldn't seek!
 javax.imageio.IIOException: Couldn't seek!
 at       com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.locateImage(TIFFImageReader.java:247)
```

Comment: It looks like `imageio` library is having problems reading your image. Do you have success with Tess4J's sample images?

Comment: Actually I gave Tess4J sample images as input.It itself shows error.

Comment: @Jeyanth Do you have the latest Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable. ?

Comment: @Tinus Jackson Sorry.. I am using Netbeans 8.0

Comment: @Jeyanth still need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable if you are using windows.

Comment: @TinusJackson Thank You.. Let me try.